Couple in brick house with no exits, symbols on floor
This is a movie that I watched in the 90s in a TV channel, I think I didn't watch to the end, I would like to know what happened in that movie
I don't know if this movie was made in the 90s, so it can be a movie from 80s? I really don't know and sorry if I have not much info
I remember that in the movie there is a couple (don't remember if there were children) and they were inside their house and suddenly they can't go out the house because the door and windows are blocked with bricks(?) or something that don't let them go out the house
They start to see signs in the floor, something related to aliens(?) or something like that

What language was the movie in? Also, you're probably going to have to provide way more detail than that.

I watched with spanish audio but I think it was a movie from USA, sorry, dont have more details,

could be http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088909 which is on youtube in English http://youtu.be/XBQbPvcqtDU and Spanish http://youtu.be/kLRMBWfypnQ

Sounds like that classic spook/horror house approach. Anything else standing out possibly?

@dav1dsm1th wow that's the movie, well it wasn't a movie it was a serie, and it's was a british serie, I watched again and I remembered many things, thanks for the links man!! can you post as answer? so I can accept it

You may be looking for Hammer House of Mystery and Suspense: Season 1, Episode 12 - Child's Play which is available on YouTube (for now) in English and Spanish
(converted from a lucky guess in a comment)
